# Como selecionar vários radios button na mesma coluna de uma tabela html?

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap

Tenho uma table html com 3 colunas e 3 linhas e quando seleciono, por exemplo botão radio da linha numero 2 a linha número 1 desmarca.

```
 @if (Model != null && Model.Tabela1!= null && Model.Tabela1.Count > 0)
                        {
                            for (int i = 0; i < Model.Tabela1.Count; i++)
                            {
    <table id="tbl" class="table table-bordered table-hover dataTable">
        <thead>
            <tr role="row">
                <th>Inserir</th>
                <th>Excluir</th>
                <th>Descrição</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>    
            <tr role="row" data-row-index="0">
                <td data-id="@Model.Tabela1[i].id"><input name="chkSelecionar" id="chkSelecionaInsere" type="radio"/></td>
                <td data-id="@Model.Tabela1[i].id"><input name="chkSelecionar" id="chkSelecionaExcluir" type="radio"/></td>
                <td>@Model.Tabela1.descricao</td>
            </tr>

}
                        }
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Obs.: Caso fosse viável poderia trocar o Radio button pelo Checkbox.

Comment: para isso existem os checkbox

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para isso não acontecer você tem que mudar o nome deles, senão o navegador interpreta como se fosse 1:

```
<table id="tbl" class="table table-bordered table-hover dataTable">
    <thead>
        <tr role="row">
            <th>Inserir</th>
            <th>Excluir</th>
            <th>Descrição</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>    
        <tr role="row" data-row-index="0">
            <td data-id="1"><input name="chkSelecionar0" id="chkSelecionaInsere0" type="radio"/></td>
            <td data-id="1"><input name="chkSelecionar0" id="chkSelecionaExcluir0" type="radio"/></td>
            <td>@Model.descricao</td>
        </tr>
        <tr role="row" data-row-index="0">
            <td data-id="2"><input name="chkSelecionar1" id="chkSelecionaInsere1" type="radio"/></td>
            <td data-id="2"><input name="chkSelecionar1" id="chkSelecionaExcluir1" type="radio"/></td>
            <td >@Model.descricao</td>
        </tr>
        <tr role="row" data-row-index="0">
            <td data-id="3"><input name="chkSelecionar2" id="chkSelecionaInsere2" type="radio"/></td>
            <td data-id="3"><input name="chkSelecionar2" id="chkSelecionaExcluir2" type="radio"/></td>
            <td>@Model.descricao</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Considere mudar o id também, poes o `id` deve sempre ser único

Comment: Verdade, vou alterar na resposta, obrigado.